# WP_Query not looking at child category

Tags: categories, wp-query, loop

Hi all I have a loop that shows a post on a single page and puts the first category name in the variable $cat:

```
$cat = $category[0]->cat_name;?>
```

Now after the post I have a link to show related posts based on this category:

```
$catPosts1 = new WP_Query(array('category_name'=> $cat, 'orderby' => 'rand', 'posts_per_page' => 1));
    while ($catPosts1->have_posts()) : $catPosts1->the_post();
```

The problem I'm having if a Child Category is selected for the first post I.e. Under the category Phones the child category Accessories is chosen nothing is appearing in the related link area. Is there a way of making Wordpress use this child category?
Thanks

Comment: By the way I have checked the category is been stored by echoing $cat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to get the child or parent categories yourself and pass all the IDs as an array via the [`category__in` argument of WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters). You can use [`get_ancestors`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors) to get the top parent category, and get all child categories of that parent via the `child_of` argument of [`get_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories).